# treat fxml files as an object in he center pain of a borderpane

Tags: object, fxml

I have created a borderpane layout where the center pane is to be filled with one or more copies of the same UI "thing monitor" boxes.  My usecase is the user presses a button to create a seperate "thing monitor" for each of their "things".

I could brute force create n "thingMonitor.fxml" files and n "thingMonitorController.java" files and just hide the ones not being used.

But I was hoping to create an object where n of em could be instantiated into my center pane.

I am not looking for code but some advice on how to proceed.

Thanks,
Tony

Answer (score 0):

I placed an HBox in my center pane and am opening my FXML file in there.  I can open multiple copies of my UI "thing monitor" and the HBox places them next to each other.

I have some local variables in "thingMonitorController.java" and they appear to be in seperate instances of the java thingMonitorcontroller class, since they do not share the same values.

So I think this will work.

If anyone can think of any gotchas, I would appreciate the heads up.

Tony